topk aggregation operator in prometheus
I am confused about topk and the result of this query topk without(job)(2, node_cpu_seconds_total) (I removed some of the results):
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.161:9100", job="node_exporter_metrics", mode="idle"}
    1987.66
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.161:9100", job="node_exporter_metrics", mode="iowait"}
    0.61
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.161:9100", job="node_exporter_metrics", mode="irq"}
    8.31
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.161:9100", job="node_exporter_metrics", mode="nice"}
    0.09
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.161:9100", job="node_exporter_metrics", mode="softirq"}
    1.7
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.161:9100", job="node_exporter_metrics", mode="steal"}
    0

node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.166:9100", job="node_exporter_monitoring_server", mode="softirq"}
    1.62
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.166:9100", job="node_exporter_monitoring_server", mode="steal"}
    0
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.166:9100", job="node_exporter_monitoring_server", mode="system"}
    24.39
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="0", instance="192.168.56.166:9100", job="node_exporter_monitoring_server", mode="user"}
    17.72

Why is there so many results when I chose to show two of them?
Please explain a little about it because I didn't find any useful resource for this topic.

topk(2, node_cpu_seconds_total) would produce two* metrics as a result.
But topk without(job)(2, node_cpu_seconds_total) as witnessed by you produces two* metrics per each labels set filtered by expression without(job). So in your case query selects all series for node_cpu_seconds_total, groups them by same labels ignoring label job, and then returns top two* by value for each of the groups

*: no more than two.
